# Dynamic input type text doesn't work Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamic input type with a class of integer but it doesn't and it doesn't work. If I don't populate it dynamically it works.

Here is the code

```
$(function(){
    $.integer = function(e){
        var arr = "1234567890";
        var code;
        if (window.event)
            code = e.keyCode;
        else
            code = e.which;
        var char = keychar = String.fromCharCode(code);
        if (arr.indexOf(char) == -1){
            return false;
        }
    };

    $(".integer").on('keypress blur', function(e){
        return $.integer(e);
    });



});
```

It works if it's not dynamic, all I had to do is add a class integer.

```
<input type="text" class="integer">
```

I also used this code `.on()` method in jquery and it actually alerts but I can enter other characters besides "1234567890".

```
     $('#table').on('keyup blur change', '.integer', function(e){
    alert('asdf');
return $.integer(e);
    })
```

Comment: What do you want to achive with line `var char = keychar = String.fromCharCode(code);`? What will happen if you use `var char = String.fromCharCode(code);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***it's working fine.check here:-***

```js
$('#table').append('<input type="text" class="integer">');// dynamically added input-box

$(".integer").on('keypress blur', function(e){
  return $.integer(e);
});

$(function(){
    $.integer = function(e){
        var arr = "1234567890";
        var code;
        if (window.event)
            code = e.keyCode;
        else
            code = e.which;
        var char = keychar = String.fromCharCode(code);
        if (arr.indexOf(char) == -1){
            return false;
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id = "table"></div>
```

Comment: @Rbex  glad to help you. :):)